# Do static images get cached by Heroku if they're loaded from Amazon's S3 cloud servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

The title pretty much describes my entire question.
Because right now I'm wondering if my app is faster by uploading my static images to heroku or to amazon's s3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Heroku Dev Center, Heroku apps on the Aspen and Bamboo stacks use [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/) to cache output from your application. On the Cedar stack, `rack-cache` and the memcache add-on must be used. Here's some more info if you're on Aspen or Bamboo:

From the [Heroku Dev Center](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching#static_assets):

> Anything that is served from the filesystem (a Rack::File) is cached for 12 hours. Whenever you push changes, your cache is cleared (see below), and since Heroku filesystems are read-only, it’s safe to cache these for a long period.

However they mention in an aside:

> Large static assets, such as MP3s or PDFs, should generally not be included in your code tree. Use an external asset hosting service such as Amazon S3, instead. See [this article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/large-static-assets) for more information.

Comment: My app is currently on the Cedar stack. I also have the memcache add-on enabled. This means that I should just host these small image files on heroku instead of s3?

Comment: @imjp I'd say that is correct. However, best way to be sure would be to try out both and test it!

Comment: Also, the cache is not cleared on the Cedar stack when changes are pushed. `heroku run console`, then `Rails.cache.clear` must be run in order to clear the cache and view the changes to the static files such as the templates, css and javascript.

Comment: One thing to notice on S3, you have to set the expiry time on S3 as well, otherwise it won't be cached.